# Knockout: Create an organized table of buttons from observable array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to create a table (or list) that has four columns of buttons for a given amount of buttons. Once a row has four buttons it moves on to the next row. I am having trouble doing this using a knockout observable array to represent my data. The code I have below produces one row for each button, but I would like a row to have four buttons before moving to the next row. Is there a way to do this given the way my data is organized?

HTML:

```
<table>
     <tbody data-bind="foreach: chosenModelData" id="timesteps">
          <tr>
             <td><button class="btn btn-default" data-bind="attr: {disabled: $data[2]}, 
                text: $data[0], click: $parent.load_image"></button></td>
          </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Excerpt from my JS file:

```
for(var i = 0; i < json.images[0].length; i++) {
    self.chosenModelData.push([timestep[i], imgpath[i], false]);
}
```

Edit (using virtual elements):

```
<table id="mytable">
       <tbody data-bind="foreach: chosenModelData" id="timesteps">
             <!-- ko if: $index() % 4 === 0 || $index() === 0-->
                      <tr>
             <!-- /ko -->
                          <td><button class="btn btn-default" data-bind="attr: {disabled: $data[2]}, text: $data[0], click: $parent.load_image"></button></td>
             <!-- ko if: $index() % 4 === 0 || $index() === 0 -->
                      </tr>
             <!-- /ko -->
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Before:
[image]

After (using virtual elements):

[image]

Dev tools html:

```
<table id="mytable">
                    <tbody data-bind="foreach: chosenModelData" id="timesteps">
                        <!-- ko if: $index() % 4 === 0 || $index() === 0 -->
                            <tr>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                                <td><button class="btn btn-default" data-bind="attr: {disabled: $data[2]}, text: $data[0], click: $parent.load_image"></button></td>
                        <!-- ko if: $index() % 4 === 0 || $index() === 0 -->
                            </tr>
                        <!-- /ko -->

                        <!-- ko if: $index() % 4 === 0 || $index() === 0 --><!-- /ko -->

                        <!-- ko if: $index() % 4 === 0 || $index() === 0 --><!-- /ko -->

                        <!-- ko if: $index() % 4 === 0 || $index() === 0 --><!-- /ko -->

                        <!-- ko if: $index() % 4 === 0 || $index() === 0 -->
                            <tr>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                                <td><button class="btn btn-default" data-bind="attr: {disabled: $data[2]}, text: $data[0], click: $parent.load_image"></button></td>
                        <!-- ko if: $index() % 4 === 0 || $index() === 0 -->
                            </tr>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Knockout js foreach binding large data into row by row template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21561588/knockout-js-foreach-binding-large-data-into-row-by-row-template)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way is dividing your original array into chunks. This should help:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.chosenModelData = ko.observableArray();

    self.dividedChosenModelData = ko.computed(function () {
        var size = 4;
        var items = self.chosenModelData();
        return [].concat.apply([],
          ko.utils.arrayMap(items, function(elem,i) {
            return i%size ? [] : [items.slice(i,i+size)];
          })
        );
    }, self);

    self.chosenModelData.push('1');
    self.chosenModelData.push('2');
    self.chosenModelData.push('3');
    self.chosenModelData.push('4');
    self.chosenModelData.push('5');
    self.chosenModelData.push('6');
    self.chosenModelData.push('7');
    self.chosenModelData.push('8');
    self.chosenModelData.push('9');


};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Html:

```
<table>
     <tbody id="timesteps">
         <!-- ko foreach: dividedChosenModelData -->
           <tr>
              <!-- ko foreach: $data -->
                <td><button class="btn btn-default" data-bind="text: $data"></button></td>
              <!-- /ko -->
            </tr>
         <!-- /ko -->
     </tbody>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fpd94zL9/3/

Comment: This works perfectly, although it seems slow to load on the page, when I run it locally. Any tips to enhance performance? The table of buttons is created after a button is clicked on my page, that retrieves data via AJAX and stores it into the chosenModelData array.

Comment: it seems slow? how many items are you retrieving from the ajax call?

Comment: 55 items in the longest one. It might have just been a browser hiccup when I initially tried it because it seems fine now...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to do something like this?

```
<table>
     <tbody data-bind="foreach: chosenModelData" id="timesteps">
        <!-- ko if: $index % 4 === 0 -->
           <tr>
        <!-- /ko -->
             <td><button class="btn btn-default" data-bind="attr: {disabled: $data[2]}, 
                text: $data[0], click: $parent.load_image"></button></td>
        <!-- ko if: $index % 4 === 0 -->
           </tr>
        <!-- /ko -->
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This looks like what I want but the buttons are messed up for some reason when I do it: they not displaying their css or html attributes and there's less of them.

Comment: Any way you could post JSFiddle or screen shots of what you mean?  Are you applying CSS with Jquery or something?  It could be happening to early causing the styles to be messed up. @wxcoder

Comment: I've made changes to the OP and included images. CSS is not being applied with Jquery just a .css file.

Comment: If you inspect the elements in dev tools with the if's does the html look correct? By that I mean are there 4 tds in 1 tr

Comment: There is one td for every tr. Another thing I didn't mention is that I have less buttons after than before when using virtual elements.

Comment: Only way to do it is to do the pure computed that the above answer has.  It seems like this is also shown here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21561588/knockout-js-foreach-binding-large-data-into-row-by-row-template